# Jenkins reporting success when Scala fails

Tags: java, scala, jenkins

I've just been experimenting with Jenkins and setting up a few projects. One inparticular calls a shell script and the exit code from that script is picked up correctly, producing a pass/fail. Yet when I call Scala from the command line, it passes no matter what happens.

In the Execute shell box:

```
/opt/scala/2.9.1/bin/scala sdfsdfsd
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Cannot figure out how to run target: sdfsdfsd
... (stack trace removed)
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Yet doing the equivalent with Java produces a failure:

```
/opt/java/jdk1.7.0/bin/java sdfdfsd
Error: Could not find or load main class sdfdfsd
Finished: FAILURE
```

Both of these produce an exit code of 1 when running from bash (with echo $?)

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

EDIT:

Interestingly, I am seeing the same behaviour when using ant exec - when I call a shell script containing an invalid call to scala I get the expected error code, but via ant (with failonerror='true') I see zero and build successful.

Thanks

Comment: Are those '...' an indication that other commands are being executed? If I am not completely mislead, Jenkins will only pick up the exit code of the last command that is executed, so if you have another command in your script that is executed after scala fails, and this command succeeds Jenkins would still consider this a success.

Comment: Sorry, no, it is just the additional stack trace/other output from java/scala.

Comment: Have you tried 'echo $?' from within your script in Jenkins? Maybe something different if you do it from bash than over Jenkins. Also you might want to try something like 'if $? == 1 exit 1' (<- this is just pseudo code, of course ;-))

Comment: Yes I have tried that, bash prints 1 (i.e. failure) and jenkins 0. But I don't understand why? I guess I'll just use ant exec but seems overkill :)

Comment: Yeah, that seems like overkill ;-) you could try loading bash in your jenkins script, and see if that changes anything. Other than that, I'm fresh out of ideas, sorry, you've stumbled onto something weird ;-)

Comment: @pushy re: "jenkins will only pick up the last command executed", actually, it executes the shell scripts with sh -ex so it fails at the first command which fails, and doesn't execute the other commands in the script

Comment: You're right of course, messed something up there. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known bug [Scala eats exit code when piping stdin](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4771), fixed in trunk.

To patch your system, the fix is quite easy, in the $SCALA_HOME/bin/scala script, line 25ish

```
function onExit() {
  if [[ "$saved_stty" != "" ]]; then
    restoreSttySettings
    exit $scala_exit_status
  fi
}
```

Move the exit to outside the if:

```
function onExit() {
  if [[ "$saved_stty" != "" ]]; then
    restoreSttySettings
  fi
  exit $scala_exit_status
}
```

This will fix your problem (in ant as well actually, but you will have to do the same thing for scalac).